# Capture YUV frame from video playback on Android

Tags: android, video, capture, yuv

I have an application on Android that plays `video` files stored on the `SD card`. I need to capture the `YUV` information for individual frames for a processing function that the software performs.

I am currently using the stock Android `MediaPlayer` in my app. Can I use this to capture `YUV` frame information? If so, how?

Thanks,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

I Suppose, you need to capture the frame individually that you would be doing already + store the frame into memory or file and then convert it into the RGB to display it.
Refer 
[display YUV Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192982/displaying-yuv-image-in-android/9330203#9330203)