# android - Renderscript to convert NV12 yuv to RGB

Tags: android, renderscript

I write below code to convert NV12 yuv to RGB but the color is not correct.
yuv2rgb.rs

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.myexam)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

rs_allocation gYUV;
uint32_t gW;
uint32_t gH;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) YUV2RGB(uint32_t x,uint32_t y)
{
    uchar yps = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gYUV, x, y);
    uchar u = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gYUV,(x & ~1),gH + (y>>1));
    uchar v = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gYUV,(x & ~1)+1,gH + (y>>1));
    uchar4 rgb = rsYuvToRGBA_uchar4(yps, u, v);
    return rgb;
}
```

java code:

```
public Bitmap NV12_toRGB(byte[] yuv,int W,int H) {
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);
    Type.Builder yuvBlder = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs))
            .setX(W).setY(H*3/2);
    Allocation allocIn = Allocation.createTyped(rs,yuvBlder.create(),Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    Type rgbType = Type.createXY(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs), W, H);
    Allocation allocOut = Allocation.createTyped(rs,rgbType,Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

    ScriptC_yuv2rgb scriptC_yuv2rgb = new ScriptC_yuv2rgb(rs);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_gW(W);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_gH(H);
    allocIn.copyFrom(yuv);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_gYUV(allocIn);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.forEach_YUV2RGB(allocOut);

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    allocOut.copyTo(bmp);

    allocIn.destroy();
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.destroy();
    return bmp;
}
```

I guess the (x,y) is the matrix coordinate, so y should be at (x,y), u should be at ((x/2)*2,H + y/2),v should be next to u, ((x/2)*2+1,H + y/2). Sounds like this logic is wrong!

Comment: Can I convert the other way around, from RGB to NV12, with renderscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two errors need to be fixed:

1. -1 should be ~1 since x & -1 just equal to x, but x & ~1 will mask out the last bit so keep the value even.
2. The yuv matrix size not correct. since uv vector is stored at the end of the y data, so the total matrix size should be W*H*3/2.

After apply these two changes, it works fine.
java:

```
public Bitmap YUV_toRGB(byte[] yuv,int W,int H) {
        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);
        Type.Builder yuvBlder = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs))
                .setX(W).setY(H*3/2);
        Allocation allocIn = Allocation.createTyped(rs,yuvBlder.create(),Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
        Type rgbType = Type.createXY(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs), W, H);
        Allocation allocOut = Allocation.createTyped(rs,rgbType,Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        ScriptC_yuv2rgb scriptC_yuv2rgb = new ScriptC_yuv2rgb(rs);
        allocIn.copyFrom(yuv);
        scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_gW(W);
        scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_gH(H);
        scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_gYUV(allocIn);
        scriptC_yuv2rgb.forEach_YUV2RGB(allocOut);

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        allocOut.copyTo(bmp);

        allocIn.destroy();
        scriptC_yuv2rgb.destroy();
        return bmp;
    }
```

yuv2rgb.rs

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.myexam)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

rs_allocation gYUV;
uint32_t gW;
uint32_t gH;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) YUV2RGB(uint32_t x,uint32_t y)
{
    uchar yps = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gYUV, x, y);
    uchar u = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gYUV,(x & ~1),gH + (y>>1));
    uchar v = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gYUV,(x & ~1)+1,gH + (y>>1));
    uchar4 rgb = rsYuvToRGBA_uchar4(yps, u, v);
    return rgb;
}
```

Comment: Oops, -1 means 0xFFFFFFFF,so & -1 equal to do nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, `rsYuvToRGBA_uchar4` is tuned for video processing, not for camera image stream (see [the formulae](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/refs/heads/master/cpu_ref/rsCpuIntrinsicYuvToRGB.cpp#61)). I have a [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63575255/192373) that resolves this, and also supports rotation.