# Converting Camera2 API image to byte array, cropping and rotating it using renderscript

Tags: android, android-camera, renderscript, yuv

I have recently stumbled upon this stackoverflow post

[Rotating YUV image data for Portrait Mode Using RenderScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794282/rotating-yuv-image-data-for-portrait-mode-using-renderscript)

I am trying to do the same thing, to rotate the image, crop it and convert it to a byte array, so i can later on create a openCV mat from it. It is needed for real time processing and needs to be high performant, an implementation with open CV was taking around 200ms which is too long.

I have tried to implement @Alex Cohns library into my project, these are the functions I am using:

/RS Kernel

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(whatever)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

rs_allocation Yplane;
uint32_t Yline;
uint32_t UVline;
rs_allocation Uplane;
rs_allocation Vplane;
rs_allocation NV21;
uint32_t Width;
uint32_t Height;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) YUV420toRGB(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    uchar Y = rsGetElementAt_uchar(Yplane, x + y * Yline);
    uchar V = rsGetElementAt_uchar(Vplane, (x & ~1) + y/2 * UVline);
    uchar U = rsGetElementAt_uchar(Uplane, (x & ~1) + y/2 * UVline);
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion
    short R = Y + (512           + 1436 * V) / 1024; //             1.402
    short G = Y + (512 -  352 * U - 731 * V) / 1024; // -0.344136  -0.714136
    short B = Y + (512 + 1815 * U          ) / 1024; //  1.772
    if (R < 0) R == 0; else if (R > 255) R == 255;
    if (G < 0) G == 0; else if (G > 255) G == 255;
    if (B < 0) B == 0; else if (B > 255) B == 255;
    return (uchar4){R, G, B, 255};
}

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) YUV420toRGB_180(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    return YUV420toRGB(Width - 1 - x, Height - 1 - y);
}

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) YUV420toRGB_90(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    return YUV420toRGB(y, Width - x - 1);
}

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) YUV420toRGB_270(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    return YUV420toRGB(Height - 1 - y, x);
}
```

/YuvConverter.java

```
public class YuvConverter implements AutoCloseable {

private RenderScript rs;
private ScriptC_yuv2rgb scriptC_yuv2rgb;
private Bitmap bmp;

YuvConverter(Context ctx, int ySize, int uvSize, int width, int height) {
    rs = RenderScript.create(ctx);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb = new ScriptC_yuv2rgb(rs);
    init(ySize, uvSize, width, height);
}

private Allocation allocY, allocU, allocV, allocOut;

@Override
public void close() {
    if (allocY != null) allocY.destroy();
    if (allocU != null) allocU.destroy();
    if (allocV != null) allocV.destroy();
    if (allocOut != null) allocOut.destroy();
    bmp = null;
    allocY = null;
    allocU = null;
    allocV = null;
    allocOut = null;
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.destroy();
    scriptC_yuv2rgb = null;
    rs = null;
}

private void init(int ySize, int uvSize, int width, int height) {
    if (bmp == null || bmp.getWidth() != width || bmp.getHeight() != height) {
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        if (allocOut != null) allocOut.destroy();
        allocOut = null;
    }
    if (allocY == null || allocY.getBytesSize() != ySize) {
        if (allocY != null) allocY.destroy();
        Type.Builder yBuilder = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(ySize);
        allocY = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yBuilder.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    }
    if (allocU == null || allocU.getBytesSize() != uvSize || allocV == null || allocV.getBytesSize() != uvSize ) {
        if (allocU != null) allocU.destroy();
        if (allocV != null) allocV.destroy();
        Type.Builder uvBuilder = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(uvSize);
        allocU = Allocation.createTyped(rs, uvBuilder.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
        allocV = Allocation.createTyped(rs, uvBuilder.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    }
    if (allocOut == null || allocOut.getBytesSize() != width*height*4) {
        Type rgbType = Type.createXY(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs), width, height);
        if (allocOut != null) allocOut.destroy();
        allocOut = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbType, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
// Enumerate valid values for this interface
@IntDef({Surface.ROTATION_0, Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_180, Surface.ROTATION_270})
// Create an interface for validating int types
public @interface Rotation {}

/**
 * Converts an YUV_420 image into Bitmap.
 * @param yPlane  byte[] of Y, with pixel stride 1
 * @param uPlane  byte[] of U, with pixel stride 2
 * @param vPlane  byte[] of V, with pixel stride 2
 * @param yLine   line stride of Y
 * @param uvLine  line stride of U and V
 * @param width   width of the output image (note that it is swapped with height for portrait rotation)
 * @param height  height of the output image
 * @param rotation  rotation to apply. ROTATION_90 is for portrait back-facing camera.
 * @return RGBA_8888 Bitmap image.
 */

public Bitmap YUV420toRGB(byte[] yPlane, byte[] uPlane, byte[] vPlane,
                          int yLine, int uvLine, int width, int height,
                          @Rotation int rotation) {
    init(yPlane.length, uPlane.length, width, height);

    allocY.copyFrom(yPlane);
    allocU.copyFrom(uPlane);
    allocV.copyFrom(vPlane);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_Width(width);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_Height(height);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_Yline(yLine);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_UVline(uvLine);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_Yplane(allocY);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_Uplane(allocU);
    scriptC_yuv2rgb.set_Vplane(allocV);

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            scriptC_yuv2rgb.forEach_YUV420toRGB(allocOut);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            scriptC_yuv2rgb.forEach_YUV420toRGB_90(allocOut);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            scriptC_yuv2rgb.forEach_YUV420toRGB_180(allocOut);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            scriptC_yuv2rgb.forEach_YUV420toRGB_270(allocOut);
            break;
    }

    allocOut.copyTo(bmp);
    return bmp;
}
```

}

And my use case:

```
public YuvImage(Image image, int rotation,
    int cropX, int cropY, int cropWidth, int cropHeight, boolean isGreyOnly, Context context) {
    Image.Plane[] imagePlanes = image.getPlanes();
    Image.Plane yPlane = imagePlanes[0];
    ByteBuffer yBuffer = yPlane.getBuffer();

    Image.Plane uPlane = imagePlanes[1];
    Image.Plane vPlane = imagePlanes[2];

    ByteBuffer uBuffer = uPlane.getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer vBuffer = vPlane.getBuffer();

    List<byte[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add(getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(yBuffer));
    myList.add(getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(uBuffer));
    myList.add(getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(vBuffer));

    int[] strides = new int[]{yPlane.getRowStride(), yPlane.getPixelStride(), uPlane.getRowStride(), uPlane.getPixelStride(), vPlane.getRowStride(), vPlane.getPixelStride()};


    yuvTransform(myList, strides, cropWidth, cropHeight, Surface.ROTATION_90);
}


private static byte[] getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
    byte[] bytesArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.length);
    return bytesArray;
}

    private void yuvTransform(List<byte[]> bytesList, int[] strides, int width, int height, @YuvConverter.Rotation int rotation) {
    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        int _tmp = width;
        width = height;
        height = _tmp;
    }
    if (total_calls == 0) {
        long start = new Date().getTime();
        yuvConverter = new YuvConverter(context.getApplicationContext(), bytesList.get(0).length, bytesList.get(1) == null ? 0 : bytesList.get(1).length, width, height);
    }

    total_calls += 1;
    long startTime = new Date().getTime();
    /*
     * hardcoded assuptions:
     *   stride[0] (yLine) >= width
     *   stride[1] (yPixel) == 1
     *   stride[2] (uLine) >= width
     *   stride[3] (uPixel) == 2
     *   stride[4] (vLine) == uLine
     *   stride[5] (vPixel) == uPixel
     */
    Bitmap abgr = yuvConverter.YUV420toRGB(bytesList.get(0), bytesList.get(1), bytesList.get(2),
            strides[0], strides[2], width, height, rotation);

    long bitmapTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    total_bitmap += bitmapTime;

    int bitmapHeaderSize = 54 + 16;
    int bmpSize = bitmapHeaderSize + abgr.getWidth() * abgr.getHeight() * 4;
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bmpSize);
    byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();

    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    byteBuffer.put((byte) 'B');
    byteBuffer.put((byte) 'M');
    byteBuffer.putLong(byteBuffer.capacity());
    byteBuffer.putInt(bitmapHeaderSize);
    byteBuffer.putInt(40 + 16); // info header size
    byteBuffer.putInt(width);
    byteBuffer.putInt(-height);
    byteBuffer.putShort((short) 1); // planes
    byteBuffer.putShort((short) 32); // bpp
    byteBuffer.putInt(3); // BI_BITFIELDS
    byteBuffer.putInt(32);
    byteBuffer.position(54); // set XBGR
    byteBuffer.putInt(0xff);     // R
    byteBuffer.putInt(0xff00);   // G
    byteBuffer.putInt(0xff0000); // B
    byteBuffer.putInt(0x0);      // A
    byteBuffer.position(bitmapHeaderSize);
    abgr.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    data = getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(byteBuffer);

    total_convert += new Date().getTime() - startTime;
}
```

But all I get is a completely distorted image like this:

[image: result image after transformation]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

UPDATE:

After omitting the cropping part and taking the entire image, i noticed, that apparently, width and height parameters should be swapped. When i do this, I get a clearer image but the colors are still wrong:

[image: Some progress]

---

UPDATE 2:

I have managed to get the correct colors by changing the conversion formula (I found another one on the Internet)

Now the renderscript for conversion looks like this:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.mypackage);
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

int32_t width;
int32_t height;

uint inUvPixelStride, inUvRowStride;
rs_allocation yIn,uIn,vIn;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) convertYuvToRGB(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) 
{

    uint uvIndex=  inUvPixelStride * (x/2) + inUvRowStride*(y/2);

    uchar yPlane= rsGetElementAt_uchar(yIn, x, y);
    uchar u= rsGetElementAt_uchar(uIn, uvIndex);
    uchar v= rsGetElementAt_uchar(vIn, uvIndex);

    int4 argb;
    argb.r = yPlane + v * 1436 / 1024 - 179;
    argb.g =  yPlane -u * 46549 / 131072 + 44 -v * 93604 / 131072 + 91;
    argb.b = yPlane +u * 1814 / 1024 - 227;
    argb.a = 255;

    uchar4 out = convert_uchar4(clamp(argb, 0, 255));
    return out;
}
```

Comment: To debug it, start with an 'image' of 8x8 and follow your flow step by step.

Comment: Definitely do this step-by-step. Make sure your YUV->RGB code works first, then add on the rotations, and so on.  As one point, you're not accounting for UV plane pixel stride, which may be 1 or 2 (most common options). Right now you assume it's 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! For now, i will omit the cropping part. I already made some progress, the details are in the update section of the post. I guess now only the colors are wrong, but im again not sure, which part is causing it

Comment: I have finally managed to get the colors and rotation right, it seems that the renderscript conversion from YUV420 to RGB had different values, i tried out different ones and managed the conversion correctly. Now there is just one more question / task left: How can I crop the camera 2 API image to a specific Rect before doing the conversion and rotation, so I have less pixels and improve the speed?