# How can I create a YuvImage in android

Tags: android, image

I need to create a yuv image in NV21 format for testing purpose.

From this posting, [Displaying YUV Image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192982/displaying-yuv-image-in-android), I see it does:

> YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, PictureFormat.NV21, width,
>   height, null);

How can I get 'data'? to passing in yuvImage?
Can I load it from a resource file, what should be the resource file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired Parameter (data) by Converting the resource Drawable to Bytearray then use it to get the YUV image :

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_pic);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: is 'my_pic' a jpg? or what kind of file is it? Why I need to call" bitmap.compress()"?

Comment: my_pic is a drawable image, Jpg or Png .. and you need to reference 
android.graphics.Bitmap in order to use "compress" method..