# How to get width and height from YUV image file in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, fileinputstream, yuv, image-formats

I am creating a simple YUV to JPEG image converter.for that I need to get the size of YUV image from the file. I hard corded here for testing. but I need to get those details grammatically. Any help will appreciate.

```
private void covertToYuvImage() {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baoStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String yuvImagePath = selectedFolder+yuvImageList.get(0); //Path to YUV image
    File file = new File(yuvImagePath);
    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try{
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(bFile, ImageFormat.NV21,2048,1536,null);
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg( new Rect(0, 0, 2048, 1536), 100, baoStream);

    File imgFile = new File(selectedFolder, "NewImage.jpeg");
    if (!imgFile.exists()) {

        FileOutputStream img;
        try {
            img = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
            img.write(baoStream.toByteArray());
            img.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But output was horrible. Please see attached image. 
[image]

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: I haven' tried it but seems this answer will help you if you perform operation on Bitmap instead of picking image from file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960247/convert-bitmap-array-to-yuv-ycbcr-nv21

Answer (score 0):

```
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(bFile, ImageFormat.NV21,2048,1536,null);
yuvImage.compressToJpeg( new Rect(0, 0, 2048, 1536), 100, baoStream);
yuvImage.getWidth () // it will return width in int
yuvImagegetHeight() // It will return height in int
```

[Try this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html#getHeight()) hope this will help you

Comment: This will return  2048 and 1536.. but I want to know whether it is possible to get those values from YUV image file which can be used in constructor of YuvImage

Comment: Do you have any idea about output image

Comment: hope this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192982/displaying-yuv-image-in-android